# PHP multilanguage site with language files

Tags: php, multilingual

I'm making my website in 2 languages. For the language, I just load in a php file containing an array with following structure:

```
$translation = array(
    "username" => "Username",
    "something_else" => "Something else"
);
```

Then inside my main site, instead of echoing `Username` I echo out `$translation["username"]` and it works for all the languages. Now I was wondering, often a string is split up in two parts. Currently  I do:

```
"amount_of_something" => array("You have logged in","times.")
```

Then I retrieve it using `echo $translation["amount_of_something"][0] . " 5 ". $translation["amount_of_something"][1];`.

Now, for the actual **question**: is there a shorter way to do this last one? In a jQuery plugin I came across following syntax:

```
maxlength: $.validator.format("Maximum {0} characters allowed.")
```

I suppose this is done with an extra function in this example. Is there a built in method of this in php (since php has a bazillion array-function), or else what would be the most efficiënt way to do this?

I thougt it would be easy with a function, but since the amount of possible variables (it can have more than 1 value inbetween), I'm not quite sure if it's worth doing it over the method I'm using now.

I hope my question is a bit clear, if not please tell me what part of the question is not.

Comment: [sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: "You have logged in 1 times" :) Yay for singular/plural nouns. This may get beyond your scope, but if you are serious about translations, you may want to look into [GetText](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.gettext.php). It supports several plural formats, even for languages that have more than 2 of them :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [php sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) is a relevant function to mention here

Take a look at their example.

```
<?php
$num = 5;
$location = 'tree';

$format = 'There are %d monkeys in the %s';
echo sprintf($format, $num, $location);
?>
```

You could solve your problem with a similar approach. A lot of php frameworks use `sprintf` in cases as yours.

Comment: PHP has such neat functions! Didn't have a clue this was possible, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to have multiple languages is:

```
$lang = array();

$lang['Example'] = "Welcome $User";
```

Then, embedding into your website like:

```
<p> echo $lang['Example']; </p>
```

You can set cookies, and depending of which cookie is set, include a different file containining the array.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['german'])) {
   $lang = "languages/german.php";
} else {
   $lang = "languages/english.php";
}

include_once($lang);
```

Comment: You can set $User to the username of the user that is currently logged in. It was just a random example with variables

Answer (score 1):

The function you may look for is [sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). To use ur example u transform the array to a string: "You have logged in %d times".